# How to catch python syntax errors?

Tags: python, regex, error-handling, try-except

```
try:
    pattern=r'<tr><td><a href='(?P<link>[\s\S]*?)'[\s\S]*?><img src='(?P<img>[\s\S]*?)'     width='130' height='130'[\s\S]*?/></a></td>'
except:
    try:
        pattern=r"<tr><td><a href='(?P<link>[\s\S]*?)'[\s\S]*?><img src='(?P<img>[\s\S]*?)' width='130' height='130'[\s\S]*?/></a></td>"
    except:
        pattern=r"""<tr><td><a href='(?P<link>[\s\S]*?)'[\s\S]*?><img src='(?P<img>[\s\S]*?)' width='130' height='130'[\s\S]*?/></a></td>"""
```

I'm writing regular expressions through a tool, and then generate the python code. There are some situations where I need to use ' or " or """ to wrap the regular expression. I want to try/except the error. If the error is captured, then I can try another. But it didn't work. Any help?

Comment: Please.  Find a tutorial.  Do all of the tutorial.  This question indicates that you skipped some sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `try`/`except` statement in Python is used for errors that happen while your program is running. On the other hand, you are encountering errors that happen during compilation. In this case, `try`/`except` will not help you.

It looks like you would be best off always using `"""` to surround your regular expressions that contain different kinds of quotes. In Python, the only thing you can't put inside a triple-quoted string is a triple-quote.

Comment: for an instance:a="""aaa"""",it will not works too,there there some way to dynamic compile the code and try catch the error and try another one?

Comment: @mlzboy: If you're generating this code from something else, then maybe escape all your embedded quotes. So `a="aaa\""` would be `aaa` followed by one `"`.

Comment: i have process it in my way,it will cause error when use """ and the string endswith ",so at the string end i add a space,so it will not throw syntx error,after that,i do some escape, as you say above,thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes inside the RE. In your first line, all the single quotes need to be escaped as `\'`.

Don't use a try block to fix your faulty RE. Just do it right the first time.